# multiple file selection raise Server internal error in rails with carrierwave gem and jQuery-File-Upload library

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I'm work on a rails project that has an uploader as one of it's componants.

I'm using carrierwave gems and jQuery-File-Upload library to get some ajax!

when I added one more feature, that is multi choice

```
<%= f.file_field :path, multiple: "multiple" %>
```

the app stop uploading and raising `server internal error`

when I use firebug console
the error was in that line

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

without that `multiple` attribute, it works very well!
like this

```
<%= f.file_field :path %>
```

I can't imagine where this that error!

I tried to modify that working rails example called [Fily](https://github.com/banditj/fily/tree/no-asset-pipeline) to upload multiple and it failed, too!

here is my models, controllers and views as I get some probelms with pasting it here!
http://pastebin.com/e2TPpsE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :)

the multiple attribute add [] in the class name to make it like this

```
<input id="picture_path" type="file" name="picture[path][]" multiple="multiple">
```

so, in the controller modify it to be

```
@picture = Picture.new
@picture.avatar = params[:picture][:path][0]
```